# Sqlite Database Insert Statement in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite, insert

I try to insert only two integer variable to my sqlite database. I created a database which name is ups.sqlite, it has a one table (upssTable) and the table have two column. But when I open /Users/ds/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/FCB4B455-4B7F-4C47-81B6-AC4121874596/SqliteDeneme.app/ups.sqlite there is no data in ups.sqlite. My code is here:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath]; 

if(!success) {

    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ups.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

    if (!success) 
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
}   

NSLog(@"database path %@",dbPath);


if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &cruddb) == SQLITE_OK))
{
    NSLog(@"An error has occured.");
}

if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &cruddb) ==SQLITE_OK){

    NSString *  str1 =@"1";
    NSString * str2 =@"1";


    const char *sql = "INSERT INTO upssTable (column1, column2) VALUES (?,?)"; 

    NSInteger result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(cruddb,sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
    NSLog(@"upss %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(cruddb));

    if(result == SQLITE_OK)        
    {
        sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, [str1 integerValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, [str2 integerValue]);

    }
    else
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error . '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(cruddb));                        
    }
    sqlite3_reset(stmt);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(cruddb);
}
}

- (NSString *) getDBPath {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ups.sqlite"];
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Please help me. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating your sqlite3 statement, but you aren't actually executing it using `sqlite3_step()`.

Also you appear to be opening the database twice?

Answer (score 6):

You havent used sqlite3_step() at all. Try this way...

```
sqlite3 *database; 
 dbPath=[self.databasePath UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_open(dbPath,&database)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sqlstatement = "INSERT INTO upssTable (column1, column2) VALUES (?,?)"; 
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledstatement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sqlstatement , -1, &compiledstatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
             NSString *  str1 =@"1";
    NSString * str2 =@"1";
      sqlite3_bind_int(compiledstatement, 1, [str1 integerValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_int(compiledstatement, 2, [str2 integerValue]);
         if(sqlite3_step(compiledstatement)==SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                NSLog(@"done");
            }
            else NSLog(@"ERROR");
            sqlite3_reset(compiledstatement);
    }
    else
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error . '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(cruddb));                        
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: There is nice explanation by Rob. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386276/4061501)