# sqlite3_prepare_v2 / sqlite3_exec

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

Few questions about sqlite3:

1.When is necessary to use first approach one and when the other ? It is a difference between them?

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, sql_stmt_getIdRecepteur, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL);
```

and

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, sql_stmt_getIdRecepteur, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {}
```

2.When is most indicated to use 'sqlite3_exec' than 'sqlite3_prepare_v2' ?

3.When is necessary to use first one, the second or the third:

```
while(sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_ROW){}
if(sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_ROW){}
if(sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_DONE){}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. One should always check the return values of SQLite functions, in order to make sure it succeeded, thus the use of the `if` statement is greatly preferred. And if it failed, one would call `sqlite3_errmsg()` to retrieve a C string description of the error.
2. One would use `sqlite3_prepare_v2` (instead of `sqlite3_exec`) in any situation in which either:

   - one is returning data and therefore will call `sqlite3_step` followed by one or more [`sqlite3_column_xxx`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) functions, repeating that process for each row of data; or
   - one is binding values to the `?` placeholders in the SQL with [`sqlite3_bind_xxx`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).

   One can infer from the above that one would use `sqlite3_exec` only when (a) the SQL string has no parameters; and (b) the SQL does not return any data. The `sqlite3_exec` is simpler, but should only be used in these particular situations.

   Please note: That point regarding the `?` placeholders is very important: One should avoid building SQL statements manually (e.g., with `stringWithFormat` or Swift string interpolation), especially if the values being inserted include end-user input. For example, if you call `sqlite3_exec` with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statement that was created using user input (e.g., inserting some value provided by user into the database), you inherently risk the very real possibility of problems arising from un-escaped quotation marks and escape symbols, etc. One is also exposed to SQL injection attacks.

   For example, if `commentString` was provided as a result of user input, this would be inadvisable:

   ```
   NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO COMMENTS (COMMENT) VALUES ('%@')", commentString];
   if (sqlite3_exec(database, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
       NSLog(@"Insert failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
   }
   ```

   Instead, you should:

   ```
   const char *sql = "INSERT INTO COMMENTS (COMMENT) VALUES (?)";
   if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
       NSLog(@"Prepare failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
       return;
   }
   if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [commentString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK) {
       NSLog(@"Bind 1 failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
       sqlite3_finalize(statement);
       return;
   }
   if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
       NSLog(@"Step failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
   }
   sqlite3_finalize(statement);
   ```

   Note, if this proper implementation felt like it was too much work, you could use the [FMDB library](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), which would simplify it to:

   ```
   if (![db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO COMMENTS (COMMENT) VALUES (?)", commentString]) {
       NSLog(@"Insert failure: %@", [db lastErrorMessage]);
   }
   ```

   This provides the rigor of `sqlite3_prepare_v2` approach, but the simplicity of the `sqlite3_exec` interface.
3. When retrieving multiple rows of data, one would use:

   ```
   while(sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) { ... }
   ```

   Or, better, if you wanted to do the proper error handling, you'd do:

   ```
   int rc;
   while ((rc = sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
       // process row here
   }
   if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSLog(@"Step failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
   }
   ```

   When retrieving a single row of data, one would:

   ```
   if (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) != SQLITE_ROW) {
       NSLog(@"Step failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
   }
   ```

   When performing SQL that will not return any data, one would:

   ```
   if (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
       NSLog(@"Step failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
   }
   ```

---

When using the SQLite C interface, you can see that it takes a little work to do it properly. There is a thin Objective-C wrapper around this interface called [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), which not only simplifies the interaction with the SQLite database and is a little more robust.

Comment: Definitely, this should be in documentation ! Thank you

Comment: BTW, there is a bit of an [introduction on the SQLite.org site](https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html), though it doesn't go into details on when the convenience function, `sqlite3_exec`, is appropriate, and when it isn't. They leave it to you to infer this. But it does discuss the basic interface.

Comment: Should I use `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` when `sqlite3_bind_text` when run all these in Background thread? @Rob /@Anyone. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229102/when-to-use-sqlite-transient-vs-sqlite-static) when googling.

Comment: @LalKrishna - Yes, we should use `SQLITE_TRANSIENT`. I’ve updated this accordingly. FYI, it has nothing to do with background or foreground: It’s a question of whether you want SQLite to use copy semantics or not. Nine times out of ten, you do want to use `SQLITE_TRANSIENT`. As the docs say, “The `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` value means that the content will likely change in the near future and that SQLite should make its own private copy of the content before returning.”

Answer (score 1):

For **question 1**,in most cases, you need to verify that result is equal to **SQLITE_OK** to make sure your command ran successfully. (**SQLITE_OK** is **int** type**). Therefore, the second is preferred.

For **question 2**, the function **sqlite3_exec** is used to run any command that doesn't return data, including updates,inserts and deletes. Retrieving data from the database is little more involved. And the function **sqlite3_prepare_v2** can used for **SELECT** (in `SQL`). In common, *create table* often use the first one.

For **question 3**, well, **while** is for **loop**, while **if** is for **condition**. Generally, if you retrieve dada from db, you need a *loop* to traverse the *return array**. If you *insert* a data to db (for instance), you can use *SQLITE_DONE* to check you operation.

By the way, **core data** is preferred in IOS for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer to #2 that I just found: use `sqlite3_exec` (or use `sqlite3_prepare_v2` in a loop) when `sql_stmt_getIdRecepteur` actually contains multiple SQL statements.  From the [docs for `sqlite3_prepare_v2`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html):

> These routines only compile the first statement in zSql, so *pzTail is left pointing to what remains uncompiled.

`sqlite3_exec` includes an internal loop that calls `sqlite3_prepare_v2` multiple times until the entire input string is compiled.  If you don't use `sqlite3_exec`, and you have multiple SQL statements in a string, you need to check the `pzTail` return value from `sqlite3_prepare_v2`.